# Copying files across network drives

Tags: command-line, file-transfer

I have the following copy batch file that works fine locally.

```
FORFILES /P C:\Users\Documents\TestingFolder\PDFs\ /M *Daily*.pdf /S /C "cmd /c copy @file C:\Users\Documents\TestingFolder\MovedPDFs\"
```

this moves all the PDFs from one folder to another without the subfolders.

This portion works fine.....

But when I change the source folder to my network drive it does not work

```
FORFILES /P C \\10.62.12.50\e\system\mwshares\ Documents\TestingFolder\PDFs\ /M *Daily*.pdf /S /C "cmd /c copy @file C:\Users\Documents\TestingFolder\MovedPDFs\"
```

I get UNC Paths not supported.

Both drives are shared and I have administrative permissions.

I can copy the files manually just fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you actually have a space in `mwshares\ Documents`? And why is there a  `C` in `FORFILES /P C`?

Comment: "\\10.62.12.50" is a UNC path. I have a hunch that "UNC paths not supported" refers to this. Seriously though, I am not certain, but this error may be coming from the CMD call and I think it may be related to the CMD working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) instead.  The syntax would be a lot simpler, and it handles UNC paths just fine.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have permissions to load any new software..

Comment: Robocopy is not 3rd party software.  It's native to all versions of Windows Vista and later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i do not have permissions to add new software to the PC.
I actually got it to work ( Kinda sorta )
I use xcopy to load the folders and files to the local machine
Then i use forfiles to strip out the directories leaving me with just the PDFs that i wanted.
Then i use another xcopy to load tthe PDFs onto the administrative server.
These are on one batch file that works exactly like i wanted it to .

The only issue left is the permissions.  If i am logged onto the PC as an administrator it works great.  but if it logs off, it stalls out on the second xcopy to the Administrations server.  My IT dept is working on that part.

I do have an administrative rights on all 3 machines. But with these corporate machines it still limits me somewhat. On the local PC the screen saver auto logs you out.  We are not allowed to change that setting.

I have tried running Runas /user:xxxxxx\xxxxxxx/savecred
but it still did nto work...   the IT department is looking into how to leave me a mapped drive that will allow the transfer even when logged out.  I want the batch file to run at 6:30am before anybody gets to the office.

this is my most recent update

Thanks for all yalls help